# yum install always fails with the error in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, yum

404 Errors:

```
[Errno -1] Metadata file does not match checksum
Trying other mirror.
[Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
```

I tried:

```
rm -fr /var/cache/yum/*
yum clean all
yum clean all && yum clean metadata && yum clean dbcache && yum makecache && yum update
```

Still no effects. What else can I do?

I will list my repositories files in `/etc/yum.repos.d` directory:

```
CentOS-Base.repo
CentOS-CR.repo
CentOS-fasttrack.repo
CentOS-Sources.repo
epel.repo
CentOS-Base.repo.rpmnew
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
CentOS-Media.repo
CentOS-Vault.repo
epel-testing.repo
OpenLogic.repo
```

My `yum.conf` content is:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release
http_caching=packages

#  This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata
# is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to
# download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct
# information.
#  It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like
# Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking
# interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something
# manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this).
# metadata_expire=90m

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
#proxy=http://proxy.com:8080
#proxy_username=xxx
#proxy_password=kkk
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable the caching on your `yum.conf` : `http_caching=none` and disable the fastestmirror on your `fastestmirror.conf` file by changing the value of `enabled` from `1` to `0` then type the following command:

```
yum clean metadata
yum clean all
```

**Edit**
To temporarily disable the plugin, add `–disableplugin=fastestmirror` to your `yum` command line. For example `yum update –disableplugin=fastestmirror` .

To permanently disable the plugin, edit `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf`
and change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`

Comment: where can I found fastestmirror.conf file

Comment: /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo.rpmnew` then edit`/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and enable main repository by un-commenting `baseurl=` line and commenting `mirrorlist=` line .